# How do I set my IP address in Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, ip-address

I need to change my IP address in Windows Vista.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Changing an IP (v4) Address in Windows Vista

1. Click Start and then Control Panel

   [image]
2. Click to enter Classic View on the left if you are not already in it.
3. Enter the Network and Sharing Center

   [image]
4. Click Manage Network Connections in the left pane. (tip: to get here quicker, just hit your Start button and type `ncpa.cpl`)

   [image]
5. Right-click on the device you wish to set the IP address and click Properties

   [image]
6. Highlight Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) and click Properties

   [image]
7. This is the tricky part. You need to know yourself what to put in here.

   [image]

*In step 7, I entered details that are relevant to me. The default gateway is set on your modem / router. This bit is crucial. The IP address I entered was within the range allowed on my modem and the subnet mask fills itself in depending on how you typed your IP.*

Answer (score 3):

http://www.ehow.com/how_2056398_change-ip-address-windows-vista.html

Comment: Indeed, you are right.  And I actually looked at that page before asking the question here.

Sorry if my question unnecessarily deteriorated the quality of the SU community.

Comment: Is there something in that tutorial that you needed some extra explanation on? This question is completely valid for SU, just rather simple. You didn't mention any other details besides changing an IP in vista. Is there more to the question?

Comment: Not really.  I misread the link you gave (before I asked the question) and thought I wasn't finding what I wanted.  Since I'm really inexperienced with things like ip addresses, I lacked confidence, and decided to ask.

Comment: That is ok, that is why websites like this exist. Do not feel bad if you need to ask for further clarification or need help with a tutorial.

Comment: Edit: removed my that took .89 seconds google comment.

Answer (score 2):

And if you prefer the command-line way of doing it:

```
netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" source=static addr=<ip address> mask=<subnet mask> gateway=<default gateway> gwmetric=0
```

Obviously the name has to be right, so list the available connections and their names to figure out which one to set:

```
netsh interface show interface
```

Gateway can be left out if it doesn't need changing. To set the DNS servers to something else as well:

```
netsh interface ip set dns name="Local Area Connection" source=static addr=<dns address>
netsh interface ip add dns name="Local Area Connection" addr=<additional dns address>
```

For completeness, to reset the connection to DHCP (automatically assign IP address and DNS servers):

```
netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" dhcp
netsh interface ip set dns name="Local Area Connection" dhcp
```

Comment: Someone's "commenting": Oskar, i stuck at DNS commands, your commands helped me to add the secondary DNS without any issues...awesome...thank you..Cheers, SM